# What does the "Images" tab show on Tensorboard?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorboard

After launching the tensorboard, I see 3 rows of images under the "IMAGES" tab, along with a relative path url to the left. Can someone tell me what do these images and relative paths represent? What do the images in 1st and 2nd column represent?

I have attached an image for reference.

[image]

Comment: I secretly suspect that nobody really understands TensorBoard.

Answer (score 4):

The relative path URL relates to TensorFlow's way of dealing with variables.

You might want to browse the Documentation on "name_scope", "variable_scope" and "Sharing Variables". A good start would be [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/how_tos/variable_scope/index.html)

As you are doing images with Tensorflow, you might be interested in visualizing your filter kernels. In [this](http://robromijnders.github.io/tensorflow_basic/) projects, I have working code to visualize the kernels of the first layer within TensorBoard

Comment: What do the images in 1st and 2nd column represent? I didn't understand what exactly tensorboard wants to display on this page!

Answer (score 2):

From the tensorboard [readme](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.10/tensorflow/tensorboard/README.md) file:

> The dashboard is set up so that each row corresponds to a different
>   tag, and each column corresponds to a run.